# Calculate wall to monotonic clock by hand

Tags: c++, linux, time

For a specific task I am trying to generate the values in the `struct vdso_data` by hand. This is the struct from the Linux 4.9 kernel which I am trying to generate.

```
struct vdso_data {
    __u64 cs_cycle_last;    /* Timebase at clocksource init */
    __u64 raw_time_sec; /* Raw time */
    __u64 raw_time_nsec;
    __u64 xtime_clock_sec;  /* Kernel time */
    __u64 xtime_clock_nsec;
    __u64 xtime_coarse_sec; /* Coarse time */
    __u64 xtime_coarse_nsec;
    __u64 wtm_clock_sec;    /* Wall to monotonic time */
    __u64 wtm_clock_nsec;
    __u32 tb_seq_count; /* Timebase sequence counter */
    /* cs_* members must be adjacent and in this order (ldp accesses) */
    __u32 cs_mono_mult; /* NTP-adjusted clocksource multiplier */
    __u32 cs_shift;     /* Clocksource shift (mono = raw) */
    __u32 cs_raw_mult;  /* Raw clocksource multiplier */
    __u32 tz_minuteswest;   /* Whacky timezone stuff */
    __u32 tz_dsttime;
    __u32 use_syscall;
};
```

I am having trouble generating the `wtm_clock_sec` and `wtm_clock_nsec`.

This is what I have tried, using real values from a running system.

```
#include <iostream>

void calculate_wall_to_monotonic(
        uint64_t raw_time_sec, uint64_t raw_time_nsec,
        uint64_t x_time_sec, uint64_t x_time_nsec,
        int32_t cs_shift) {
    uint64_t wtm_clock_sec = raw_time_sec - x_time_sec;
    uint64_t wtm_clock_nsec = ((raw_time_nsec - x_time_nsec) >> cs_shift);

    std::cout << "wtm_clock_sec: " << wtm_clock_sec << " Expected 18446744072016585089" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "wtm_clock_nsec: " << wtm_clock_nsec << " Expected 829829906" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    uint64_t raw_time_sec = 52392U;
    uint64_t raw_time_nsec = 14650919933824323U;
    uint64_t x_time_sec = 1693018919U;
    uint64_t x_time_nsec = 728684335894714U;
    uint64_t wtm_clock_sec = 18446744072016585089U;
    uint64_t wtm_clock_nsec = 829829906U;
    int32_t cs_shift = 24;

    calculate_wall_to_monotonic(raw_time_sec, raw_time_nsec, x_time_sec, x_time_nsec, cs_shift);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
wtm_clock_sec: 18446744072016585089 Expected 18446744072016585089
wtm_clock_nsec: 829829907 Expected 829829906
```

As you can see, it is off by 1 nano second.
What is wrong with my calculation?

**Edit:** Switched from xtime coarse to normal xtime because it has higher precision. Still off by 1 nano second.

**Edit 2:** Change signness.

Comment: @Bob__ Because I did not think it mattered because the calculations themselves were in the correct sign. To show this I have updated the code with the correct signs. It results in the same issue.